# Android Invisible Remote Views

Tags: android

So I am building a media player app and need some direction from anyone who knows.

Since I am forced to show a notificaiton, just to control lock screen wallpaper back to android 4 I am wonder now, if a remote view has the ability to be Visibility>INVISIBLE OR GONE.

This question is mainly just to get a yes or no answer from someone who make know since I am short on time now and don't wanna chase after something that may not be possible.

Comment: [`RemoteViews#setViewVisibility()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setViewVisibility(int,%20int))

Comment: Thanks Mike, you don't know if I can control the lock screen wallpaper with remote views do you?
Really cannot find a definitive answer for this.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. From a `Notification`, you can signal your app to do whatever it could do normally.

Comment: Thanks Mike. 
When the device is locked, the remote views will be displayed on the lock screen. Just wandering if it's possible to also set a lock screen wallpaper using remote views since remtoeControClient is depriciated

Comment: Oh, that's what you mean. I don't know.